# generic array creation error

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying to make a Graph class with generic vertices and adjacency lists and I am getting a generic array creation error at line 10 of the following code. Earlier I was getting the same error at line 11 but it was solved by casting. But this error remains. What is wrong in the code?

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Graph<T> {
    private int numVertices;
    private T[] vertex;
    private HashSet<T>[] adjacent;

    public Graph(int numVertices) {
            this.numVertices = numVertices;
            vertex = (T[]) new T[numVertices];
            adjacent = (HashSet<T>[]) new HashSet[numVertices];
    }
}
```

Comment: @downvoter: why is it downvoted? I can't see a problem with this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix arrays with collections. Use just collections:

```
private List<HashSet<T>> adjacent;
```

You can then choose to use ArrayList as a List implementation. It's same efficient and more flexible.

Comment: Thanks.. Now I am not getting any errors just unchecked/unsafe operations warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create generic arrays in java because of type erasure.

However, you can use [`Array.newInstance(Class<T>, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) to create one for you. You will have to cast the returned `Object` to `T[]`.

/e1
This still leaves the the problem of getting a `Class<T>` object. The best (only way I can think of) to do this is to have another parameter in your constructor which takes the class object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an array of an unknown type (because an array contains its component type at runtime). But for your purpose you just need to create an `Object[]`, which can contain any object.

You have two options:

1. Use a variable of type `Object[]`. You may have to cast to `T` when you get elements out and want to use it as a `T`.
2. Use a variable of type `T[]` (`vertex = (T[]) new Object[numVertices];`). This has the convenience of not having to cast to `T` when you get things out. However, you have to make sure not to pass or return this reference to code outside of the class that expects a `T[]`, which will cause a class cast exception.